# pyqtSignal emit signal between class instances

Tags: pyqt5

There is a flask server and a window application. When the server receives "1", i need to write it in QLineEdit. But I can`t get a signal.

1:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject
app=Flask(__name__)
class Communicate(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal([int], [str])
communicate = Communicate()
@app.route('/receive')
def receive():
    value = request.args.get('value')
    if value ==1:
        communicate.signal.emit('Received 1')
    return 'OK'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

2:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit
from servak import communicate

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit(self)
        communicate.signal.connect(self.line_edit.setText)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyApp()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1. Please ***ALWAYS*** check the post preview before submitting, if your code doesn't display as expected it means that somebody will have to use *their* time to fix it for you, while in the meantime other people will just ignore your post because its code is unreadable; 2. It's unclear what script is actually run first and how the second is started; if the first one is the one that is actually used as "main", the second is never called from it, and if you're hoping that you could run the second on a separate process you're clearly *wrong*, as objects are persistent within the same process.